# Angular 2 JSON object error

Tags: javascript, json, angular

every body help me.

I call create the json object

```
bank_data={
 "arr":[{"sysKey":"","bankId":"","bankName":"","bankBranch":""}],
 "searchText":"","pageSize":10,"currentPage":1,"totalCount":0
};
```

and I create the method like this:

```
 showList() { 
      let url:string =this.ics._apiurl + 'service001/getAllBankData';
      let json:any = this.bank_data;
      this.http.doPost(url,json).subscribe(data =>{
         this.bank_data =data;
      },
      error=>alert(error),
           () =>{});           
 }
```

And then I call the method from two different part of the program.
First is constructor like this:

```
constructor(private ics: RpIntercomService, 
             private _router: Router,
             params: RouteParams, 
             private http: RpHttpService, 
             private ref: RpReferences) { 

      this.showList();       
}
```

This is ok no error.

Second call is :

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="showList()">Show All</button>
```

When I click the button the object "bank_data" is null.This is Why.Please explain me.

Comment: Did you try `this.bank_data =data.json();`?

Comment: I guess that http.doPost is something you built, Can you share it's code? Also, did you try to put break point inside the subscribe to see what is data that been fetched? maybe your http request response is null...

Comment: Thank for your comment.I try with your code `this.bank_data =data.json();`

Comment: But,It is not ok.I found the error like this "TypeError: data.json is not a function"